# Loop in async function until message is received

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to stream events from a salesforce platform event but I want to loop data until an event takes place and a message is received. In my python file I have the function that I want to loop in the spot where *Loop code here until message comes in* is. Is it possible to continue looping code in this area and just have it check if a message has been received once each loop? Right now the code gets hung up on:]

async for message in client:

And the loop doesn't continue and nothing else occurs until a message is received at which point it just executes the code below where I listen for the message

```
async def subscribeToSalesforce():
    async with SalesforceStreamingClient(
            # Connect to Salesforce streaming API
            consumer_key='<>',
            consumer_secret='<>',
            username='<>',
            password='<>',
            sandbox=True) as client:
        # Subscribe to one or more topics
        await client.subscribe("/event/NewEmail__e")

        while True:
            *Loop code here until message comes in*
            # listen for incoming messages
            async for message in client:
                topic = message["channel"]
                data = message["data"]
                print(f"{topic}: {data}")
                data = data['payload']
                try:
                    print(data['Assigned__c'])
                    if data['Assigned__c']:
                        if data['Assigned__c'] == 'Assigned':
                            if data['OwnerID__c'] == currentUserID:
                                print(data)
                                findType(data)
                except:
                    print('Exception')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(subscribeToSalesforce())
```

Answer (score 0):

A better strategy would be to make a completely separate task for reading messages from the client.  This task would parse the messages as you are currently doing, and then add them to an asyncio.Queue.

The various forms of Queue offer a much richer interface for you to work with. Your other task(s) can use a `queue.get_nowait()` which will return an item if it's there and otherwise raise an exception which you can catch.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time ever working with asyncio so I wasn’t aware of the queue option. I’m going to try and implement this tomorrow at work.